# Squid + Apache error

Tags: iptables, squid, apache-2.4

I had my Apache webserver perfectly configured and everything worked fine. I asked my friend to setup a cache proxy to make my web answers faster.

So here's what he did (if I understand the `history`):

- setup squid proxy
- add iptable routing

And that's it.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

He thought everything was okay but **no**.
Now **only** me and him can access to my websites... where should I look?

Here's what I thought: "this is just a simple redirection, so I could comment the squid firewall rule and everything should work like it was *before* squid proxy".

If I try to comment the previous rule, restart iptables, and restart Apache webserver, I get  "rejected connexion". What should I do?

Comment: You could check if there are no others iptables rules using `iptables -L -n -v` and also verify the squid config file to check for some ACL and directive `http_access allow...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache probably does not listen on port 80.
Look your apache configuration and search for `Listen` directives and the `VirtualHost` directives.
You friend probably trashed / altered them.

Another possibility is that you did not cleared the nat rule from iptables and stopped the squid server.

I bet for the first solution, but can't be sure with the few infos you provide.

Then for the broken configuration, it is difficult to diagnose it without the configurations files for Apache, Squid, and your iptables setup.

If you want more help you should provide them.
For iptables configuration run `iptables-save` and copy paste the output.
Also it would be interesting to know the network configuration of your server:
* does it have one or several network interface ?
* Do you access it on lan? Or is it hosted at a remote location?

Comment: You were right: it's the second point that was the right solution. Thank you ;)